# What is the probability that a person wearing a blue t-shirt will sit next to one wearing red?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

9 people sit in a row linearly. 2 dressed in Red, 3 blue and 4 in yellow. What is the probability that a person in blue will sit next to a person in red? Why?

RRBBBYYYY this sequence from what I gather can be arranged in 9! ways.

1. Attempt

There are 2 groups R and Y we want to seat together. The Y(people wearing yellow) can be arranged in 4! ways and people wearing red in 2! ways. 
Therefore 2 x 3! x 2! should be the right answer.

Times 2 because we only want to consider two groups. (I think this is where I am going wrong because there are 3) If there were two groups of people the. i am guessing it would be right. However there are 3 groups and I have no idea how to show it.

2. Attempt

There is a total lf 9!/2!x3!x4 = 1260 ways they can be seated. These however will be in random order and I can't figure out how to put them in an order that R sits next to Y.

Comment: how the seats are placed? circularly? linearly? please, improve your question by adding more details. Moreover, what did you try to solve this problem? Please, post your efforts too.

Comment: I have made changes I hope it is clearer.

Comment: I'm sure it is. Trying to think

Comment: @PlatinumMaths What progress have you made?

Comment: If they are at a football match, then I'd say: quite small.

Answer (score 2):

Since an incorrect execution of Graham Kemp's hint has been posted, I'll post what I believe to be a correct one.

First, add a fifth yellow person and close the row into a circle. Each of the linear arrangements is obtained in exactly one way by removing one of the yellow people from a circular arrangement, and the corresponding arrangements agree on whether a red and a blue person sit next to each other, so we get the same probability by considering the circular arrangements, which obviates cumbersome case distinctions for the margins.

Now we have five compartments. If the two reds are in the same compartment, glue them together in one of $2$ orders, glue a yellow to either side of them, choosing the yellows in $5\cdot4=20$ ways, and permute the resulting $7$ objects in $(7-1)!=6!$ cyclically inequivalent ways. If they're in adjacent compartments, choose one of $2$ orders for them, glue a yellow to either side and one between them, choosing the yellows in $5\cdot4\cdot3=60$ ways, and permute the resulting $6$ objects in $(6-1)!=5!$ cyclically inequivalent ways. If they're in non-adjacent compartments, glue two yellows on either side of each of them, choosing the yellows in $5!=120$ ways, and permute the resulting $6$ objects in $(6-1)!=5!$ cyclically inequivalent ways. The total is $2\cdot20\cdot6!+2\cdot60\cdot5!+120\cdot5!=57600$. Without restrictions, we have $(10-1)!=9!=362880$ cyclically inequivalent arrangements. Thus the probability not to have a red and a blue adjacent is $\frac{57600}{362880}=\frac{10}{63}$, and the complementary probability to have a red and a blue adjacent is $1-\frac{10}{63}=\frac{53}{63}\approx84\%$, in agreement with BruceET's simulation.

Answer (score 2):

Following Graham Kemp's suggestion, first line up the yellow shirts in a row, creating 5 gaps.

1) If the red shirts are in the same gap, there are 5 choices for their gap and then $\binom{6}{3}$ ways to place the 3 blue shirts in the remaining 4 gaps; so this gives $5\binom{6}{3}$ possibilities.

2) If the red shirts are in different gaps, there are $\binom{5}{2}$ choices for their gaps and then $\binom{5}{3}$ ways to place the 3 blue shirts in the remaining 3 gaps; so this gives $\binom{5}{2}\binom{5}{3}$ possibilities.

Therefore the probability that a blue shirt is next to a red one is given by

$\hspace{.3 in}\displaystyle 1-\frac{5\binom{6}{3}+\binom{5}{2}\binom{5}{3}}{\binom{9}{4}\binom{5}{3}}=1-\frac{100+100}{1260}=1-\frac{10}{63}=\frac{53}{63}$

Comment: nice answer ! (+1)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** It might be easier to count the complement.

How many equally probable ways can you arrange two red and three blue shirts such that they are separated into five colour-separated boxes (with the four yellow shirts forming 'walls' so there is at least one between any red and blue shirt)

Comment: This was also my first thought; but it doesn't work that way, since reds and blues can form clusters and thus don't necessarily need five compartments. (BTW, I think it should say "three blue shirts" where it says "five".)

Comment: @joriki It does work that way.  If you don't want a red shirt to sit next to a blue shirt you need to put at least one yellow shirt between each cluster.  You just need to ensure you are counting *equally* probable ways to arrange them so.

Comment: Ah, I see, I misunderstood. Then it's not entirely trivial to count the number of ways of filling those boxes.

Comment: It's not entirely trivial, but its not that hard.

Comment: True. And your warning about counting equiprobable ways was apt, considering the anwers given :-)

Answer (score 0):

Comment: (If I understand the problem properly.)

In case it is of assistance checking analytical results, here is
a simulation in R that approximates the distribution of $X,$ the number of red-blue adjacencies, for people randomly
seated in a row. The program uses a trick in assigning numbers
to colors so that the absolute difference is 1 whenever a red
shirt is next to a blue one. I believe $P(X \ge 1)$ is the answer
to your problem.

```
 shirts = c(1,1,2,2,2,5,5,5,5) # 1=Red, 2=Blue, 5=Yellow
 m = 10^6; rb.adj = numeric(m) # rb.adj = nr red-blue adjacencies
 for (i in 1:m) {
  perm = sample(shirts, 9)
  rb.adj[i] = (sum(abs(diff(perm))==1)) }
 mean(rb.adj >= 1)  # aprx P(X >= 1)
 ##  0.841706  
 table(rb.adj)/m   # aprx dist'n of X
 ## rb.adj
 ##        0        1        2        3        4 
 ## 0.158294 0.436611 0.321367 0.079765 0.003963
```

A million performances of the experiment should give results
accurate to two (maybe three) places. Any arrangement with BRBRB
has $X = 4$ and $P(X = 4) = 12(5!)/9! \approx 0.004,$ which
is a little too small reliably to approximate with small relative error. (I 'cheated' by showing the best of three simulation runs.)